# Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath:

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

why this comes occasionally in selenium java, when I print the element I found
***Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath:***
when I print other elements usually like this
***[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (25f238cd0f65e6332256868f1675519e)]***

these proxy element consumes time also

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? We can't help you if we dont know what you have done.

Comment: Why would you print an element reference?

Answer (score 2):

Proxy elements are ones defined using PageFactory

Comment: What is meant by proxy element in page factory?

Answer (score 0):

The default element locator, which will lazily locate an element or an element list on a page. This class is designed for use with the PageFactory and understands the annotations `FindBy` and `CacheLookup`. If you take off PageFactory from your script or from code evaluation during debug time, the problem will be solved